# Como resuelvo el problema de la CORS en React Native consilta API Web3 red TRON

Tags: api, react-native, cors, solidity

Tengo una aplicación en react native y no sé como solucionar el problema de las CORS, lo he intentado de 3 maneras y ninguna me funciona, agradezco mayor claridad de como puedo solucionarlos

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import "./TronLinkInfo.scss";

export default class TronLinkInfo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      accountAddress: "Billetera NO conectada",
      accountBalance: "Billetera NO conectada",
      accountBandwidth: "Billetera NO conectada"
    };
  }

  
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => this.fetchAccountAddress(),10000);
    setInterval(() => this.fetchAccountBalance(),1000);
    setInterval(() => this.fetchAccountBandwidth(),1000);
  };


  async fetchAccountAddress() {

    const account =  await window.tronWeb.trx.getAccount();
    //const account = await window.tronWeb.trx.getAccount(); 
    const accountAddress = account.address;
     const accountAddressInBase58 = window.tronWeb.address.fromHex(
       accountAddress
     );

    this.setState({
      accountAddress: accountAddressInBase58
    });
  }

  async fetchAccountBalance() {
    const balanceInSun = await window.tronWeb.trx.getBalance(); //number
    const balanceInTRX = window.tronWeb.fromSun(balanceInSun); //string
    //const changeBackToSun = window.tronWeb.toSun(balanceInTRX); //string

    this.setState({
      //accountBalance: balanceInSun // Muestra el balance en SUN
      accountBalance: balanceInTRX
    });
  }
  //
  // // La funcion aqui abajo muestra el ancho de banda como un numero
  async fetchAccountBandwidth() {
    const accountBandwidth = await window.tronWeb.trx.getBandwidth(); // number

    this.setState({
      accountBandwidth: accountBandwidth
    });
  }


  render() {
    const { accountAddress, accountBalance, accountBandwidth,} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="col-lg-5 mb-5">
        <div className="card wow bounceInUp">
            <i className="fa fa-address-card-o"></i>
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">Información de la cuenta</h5>
            <h6 className="card-text">
              Dirección:<br></br>
               <strong><span>{accountAddress}</span></strong><br></br><br></br>
              Balance:<br></br>
               <strong><span>{accountBalance} TRX</span></strong><br></br><br></br>
              Bandwidth:<br></br>
               <strong><span>{accountBandwidth}</span></strong><br></br>
              
            </h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

y me sale esto no me muestra los datos de la consulta en la Blockchain, estoy usando la red de tron, con la api de trongrid

hago esto paar consultar el estado de la cuenta, en la red de pruebas no me da problema, pero cuando paso a la red principal me sale este problema

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://api.trongrid.io/walletsolidity/getaccount' from origin
> 'https://earntron.ml' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

esto me sale en la consola del navegador simplemente me dice que las cors, he buscado muchos tutoriales ninguno le da solucion